# how to print java String Array in jsp page.?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

Hello I am new in jsp i want to print my String array of Java file to My jsp page how to print in web page tell me .. i dont know how to do this.

```
while(rs.next()){
    count++;            
    anArray[i]=rs.getString("subject");         
    System.out.println(anArray[i]);
    i++;    
}
while(rs1.next()){   
    anArray[i]=rs1.getString("subject");            
    System.out.println(anArray[i]);         
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Could you please make a better attempt at making the question?

Comment: seems like your question is unrelated to JSP. Please include any related code and rephrase your question

Comment: i have one java file in which i try to get data from mySql table and store array "myArray" using Resultset. after this step i want to print "myArray" to web page using jsp file

Comment: how to print array on web page using jsp file

Comment: How is that Java file connected to the JSP? Is it a servlet? Is it in a method called from inside the JSP?

Comment: Are you trying to print the content of an array property of java class in JSP ? Is that what you want ?

Comment: no there is no connection with servlet.

Comment: Avoid scriptlets, use EL or tags!

Comment: @NoobUnChained how to do this?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi ... yes i have an Array in my java file i want to print that array in JSP page so that i cant print array value to web page

Comment: @Rajan: How are you passing that array to JSP from Java class ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming what you provided is an example of what you want to do in your JSP, the easiest way to do what you are tying to do is to use a [JSTL forEach](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm).

```
<c:forEach items="${yourArray}" var="myItem" varStatus="myItemStat">
  yourArray[${myItemStat.index}] = ${myItem}
</c:forEach>
```

This assumes you have passed your "yourArray" to the JSP.  There are LOTS of tutorials on how to do all of this sprinkled all over the Internet.

Answer (score 3):

In jsp page you can use this:

```
<%  
while(rs.next()){
    count++;            
    anArray[i]=rs.getString("subject");         
    out.println(anArray[i]);
    i++;    
}
while(rs1.next()){   
    anArray[i]=rs1.getString("subject");            
    out.println(anArray[i]);         
    i++;
}
%>
```

Comment: shoould i import any thing in my jsp page?

Comment: Not more than what you would import for that piece of code anyway.

Comment: @Rajan import java.sql.ResultSet

Comment: i just copy above jsp code and past in to my jsp page. it give me error

Comment: You should define rs in this scope too.

Comment: @Kumar where i should import java.sql.Resultset? do u mean in jsp file?

Comment: @navand , your point is correct, but to do all these , surely you need to import the `java class`

Comment: @navand : usage of scriptlet in JSPs are discouraged, it would be best to use JSTL foreach tag

Answer (score 2):

As i understand your, you are making the output  in console , and you are trying to print it in browser.

To get the output in browser

Just `import` the java class in `JSP` page

In JSP page between tag(<%..%>) by java class object print it in browser,

```
<%@page import="pack.sample"%>
<%
//In scriplets
Sample obj=new Sample();
String str[]=obj.printMe();//Here printMe() is a fn from Sample class which will return string array

//Now here do all stuffs with str[]
//out.println(str[0]);//It will return zeroth value of str[] in your browser
 %>
```

Comment: what is printMe() is this method of java calss?

Comment: just a method in java class,like `public String[] printMe()` here, this method will return string array

Comment: <%@ include file="/html/testi/init.jsp" %>
<%@page import="com.testi.TestiPortlet"%>


TestiPortlet obj=new TestiPortlet();
String str[]=obj.ordering(actionRequest, actionResponse);


out.println(str[0]);
 %>

Comment: If the method is ordering() is string array, the following code is correct, you can go ahead, `<%@ include file="/html/testi/init.jsp" %> `   `<%@page import="com.testi.TestiPortlet"%>`  `<%TestiPortlet obj=new TestiPortlet();   String str[]=obj.ordering(actionRequest, actionResponse);  out.println(str[0]); %>`

Comment: i have method in java file like ....... public void ordering(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException,PortletException

Comment: but when i write code that u provided in jsp file i give error like"Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - actionResponse cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - actionRequest cannot be resolved to a 
  variable" how to solve this

Comment: @rajan you are trying to use it with servlet, i am just saying it for java class not a servlet,**forget all** just create core java class code with one  method ,compile it and put it in classes directory  and import the path from jsp page,thats it, you got my point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28738/discussion-between-rajan-and-kark)

Comment: @kark : usage of scriptlet in JSPs are discouraged. try to use JSTL

Comment: @Panther..you are exactly correct.. i just answered as per the question had asked here.